# Setting DHCP Client Identifier for all interfaces in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, networking, powershell, dhcp

We currently have a use case where all interfaces need to have a custom client identifier for the dhcp server to be able to assign it correct IP Addresses.

We have been using a registry based approach it for windows 10 which works for known interfaces .
Is there a way to instead apply interface settings to new interfaces in cases where a network card was added later on.

Here is the code we currently use for the client identifier change.

```
function ConfigureDHCPWithClientID 
{
    Param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [byte[]] $ClientID)

    #get root element of TCP settings in the registry
    $registry = Get-Item "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\TcpIp\Parameters\Interfaces\*"

    # go via children
    foreach ($a in $registry) 
    {
        # add DhcpClientIdentifier property with parameter value    
        $itemPath = "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\TcpIp\Parameters\Interfaces\" + $a.PSChildName
        New-ItemProperty -Path $itemPath -Name 'DhcpClientIdentifier' -PropertyType Binary -Value $ClientID *>> $LOG_NAME
    }
}
```